# difference between getting value from DataRow

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Sample code:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // ...
    // insert column to table

    table.Columns.Add("name");

    // ...
    // insert value to table

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
         row["name"];
         row.Field<string>("name");     
    }
```

My question is:

- Is there a difference between using `row["name"]` and `row.Field<string>("name")`? Of course, the second way cast value to some type, but is there another difference?
- Which method is better to use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx), main differences described there:

> The **DataSet** class represents **null** values with the Value instance
>   of the **DBNull** class. A Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) expression
>   that accessed a column with a **null** value would generate a
>   **InvalidCastException** at run time. Additionally, **DataSet** does not
>   support **nullable** types. The Field method provides support for
>   accessing columns as **nullable** types. If the underlying value in the
>   DataSet is Value, the returned nullable type will have a value of
>   **null**.
>
> If the value of the specified **DataColumn** is null and **T** is a
>   reference type or nullable type, the return type will be **null**. The
>   Field method will not return Value.
>
> The Field method does not perform type conversions. If type
>   conversion is required, you should first obtain the column value by
>   using the Field method. The column value should then be converted to
>   another type.

The last paragraph makes a point as I've often seen numbers stored as strings in database, therefore `varchar` to `int` conversion would be required on data retrieval, so in this case using DataColumn is better, e.g.:

```
int test = row.Field<int>("Test"); // InvalidCastException
int test = Convert.ToInt32(row["Test"]); // Works like a charm
```

`DataRowExtensions.Field<T> Method (DataRow, String)` first appeared in .NET 3.5 and it "provides strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the specified row. The Field method also supports **nullable** types."

Afaik, `row["name"]` returns `object`, `row.Field<string>("name")` returns a `String`.
We shouldn't be comparing apples and pears, hence you should be asking what's better:

`row["name"].ToString()` vs `row.Field<string>("name")`
and the answer is: they're same.

Comment: So, if there aren't any difference I think second option is better. When we want cast value to int it is short way `int.Parse( row["name"].ToString())` vs `row.Field<int>("name")`

Comment: adding my 1 cent, row["name"].ToString() may cause a RuntimeException if row["Name"] is null

Comment: I've added an example where you'd use the "old" way over new one.

Comment: So to access a field that may be null, we should use a nullable type? 
 e.g. `row.Field<int?>("Text")` ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose but if you look at a definition of both that may tell you;

[DataRow.Item Property (DataColumn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035.aspx) `row["name"]`

[DataRowExtensions.Field Method (DataRow, DataColumn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383067.aspx) `row.Field<string>("name")`