# DataRow.Field<T>(string Column) throws invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, datarow

Good day,

**IDE** Visual Studio 2010
**.NET** 3.5
**Platform** WinForms

The SO question " [difference between getting value from DataRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104675/difference-between-getting-value-from-datarow) " refers.

I have a database table with a column `[ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`. When querying this table and storing the values in local variables I get an invalid cast exception; sample code:

```
string sQuery = @"
    SELECT [ID], [Description]
    FROM [Sources]
    ORDER BY [Description] ";

using (DataTable dtSources = SQLHelper.Fetch(sQuery))
{
    foreach (DataRow drSource in dtSources.Rows)
    {
        int iID = drSource.Field<int>("ID"); // InvalidCastException
        string sDescrption = drSource.Field<string>("Description");
    }
}
```

When stepping the execution and performing a "Quick Watch" on the faulty line I discovered that, by changing the line to `drSource.Field<object>("ID")`, the cell value type is that of `short` and not of `int`. Why would this happen when, in the table definition, this is clearly and `int`? Furthermore, `short` should be implicitly converted to `int` since `short` is smaller and should "fit" right?

Comment: drSource.Field<int?>("ID"). try this and let me know.

Comment: have you tried? is it working ?

Comment: See my comment below - you actually have DbNull values returned by query. So, problem in data, not in Field<T> extension.

Comment: everyone provided helpful information, thank you. in this case a "not-so-strong" conversion such as `int iID = (int)drSource["ID"];` or `int iID = Convert.ToInt32(drSource["ID"]);` did the trick (because `int iID = drSource.Field<int>("ID");` doesn't even allow implicitly casting a short to an int), but checking "castability" beforehand would probably also be a good idea.

Comment: Actually if type of field is short, you need to use Field<short>("ID"). Btw why it is short, if in database (as you provided) you have int, not small int.

Comment: yeah, about that. i was misled by a colleague of mine and in stead of investigating myself, i trusted his investigation. regardless, it made me aware of certain irregularities and now i can compensate for it. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of curiosity, what happens if you explicitly cast it yourself from the key/value collection?

```
int iID = (int)drSource["ID"];
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense since OP's `Field<int>("ID")` does the same.

Comment: No its working, better to use
int iID = Convert.ToInt32(drSource["ID"]);

Answer (score 11):

If your column is a nullable int, but you are trying to assign to an int, with a default value of 0:

```
using (DataTable dtSources = SQLHelper.Fetch(sQuery))
{ 
    foreach (DataRow drSource in dtSources.Rows)'
    { 
        int iID = drSource.Field<int?>("ID") ?? 0; 
        string sDescrption = drSource.Field<string>("Description"); 
    }
}
```

If your column is a nullable int and you want to assign to a nullable int:

```
using (DataTable dtSources = SQLHelper.Fetch(sQuery))
{
    foreach (DataRow drSource in dtSources.Rows)
    {
        int? iID = drSource.Field<int?>("ID");
        string sDescrption = drSource.Field<string>("Description"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Agree with Richard's answer just better to use,

```
int iID = Convert.ToInt32(drSource["ID"]);
```

Comment: (int)drSource["ID"] did not work for me.  Ihad to use the above answer

Comment: This is the only conversion that worked for me, while all others did not.

Answer (score 5):

According to implementation of Field extension, your field has DbNull value.

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        DataSetUtil.CheckArgumentNull<DataRow>(row, "row");
        return UnboxT<T>.Unbox(row[columnName]);
    }
```

UnboxT is a private class that provides methods for converting object to T. In your case ValueField converter is used:

```
private static class UnboxT<T>
{
    internal static readonly Converter<object, T> Unbox;

    static UnboxT()
    {
       DataRowExtensions.UnboxT<T>.Unbox =  
          new Converter<object, T>(DataRowExtensions.UnboxT<T>.ValueField);
    }

    private static T ValueField(object value)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value == value)
        {
            // You get this exception 
            throw DataSetUtil.InvalidCast(Strings.DataSetLinq_NonNullableCast(typeof(T).ToString()));
        }
        return (T) value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's reallly interesting, first of all because I get this exception using an Oracle DB, while the exact same data/table definition doesn't throw an exception on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get your row value into an int variable is to use 'object' and convert it to Int32 like so:

`int iID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<object>("ID"));`