# What's the difference when assigning a value to a field in square brackets LINQ?

Tags: linq

I have seen when coding in LINQ that when a value is assigned to a field sometimes is in this way **Table["Field"]** and any others like this **Table.Field** but can somebody explain me what's the difference please?

For example when modifying a field:

```
var ttAbccode_xRow =
    (from ttAbccode_Row in ds.ABCCode select ttAbccode_Row).FirstOrDefault();

if (ttAbccode_xRow != null) {
    ttAbccode_xRow["PI"] = 3.1416;
}
```

or

```
if (ttAbccode_xRow != null) {
    ttAbccode_xRow.PI = 3.1416;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: The first example is one accessing a value via an indexer and the second one is just using a property. The first is useful when there are a lot of values and you dont want to extend the class always when new values added needed. The second one is type safe and readable.

Comment: And it's not "declaring a field" at all...

Comment: Hi @TravisJ for example when modifying a field:

var ttAbccode_xRow = (from ttAbccode_Row in ds.ABCCode
            select ttAbccode_Row).FirstOrDefault();
        
if (ttAbccode_xRow != null)
{
     ttAbccode_xRow["PI"] = 3.1416;
}


or


var ttAbccode_xRow = (from ttAbccode_Row in ds.ABCCode
            select ttAbccode_Row).FirstOrDefault();
        
if (ttAbccode_xRow != null)
{
     ttAbccode_xRow.PI = 3.1416;
}

Comment: Hi @GaneshR. where can I find more information about you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between getting value from DataRow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104675/difference-between-getting-value-from-datarow)

Comment: I don't think this has anything specifically to do with LINQ. You have retrieved some object from the `ds.ABCCode` collection. Whatever object you have retrieved has either an indexer (first example), a property (second example), or both.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing field via indexer (square brackets) returns object data type. That means that your compiler cannot detect data types incompatibility. You could assing for example string value (eg. "abcd") and you won't get error at design time, but as late as at runtime.

Second method (if available in your result set) is much more safe. Your property will have proper data type hence compiler will detect data types incompatibility at design time.

If I had both access methods available I would always prefer second one. It is less error prone.