# DataTable type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, lambda, datatable

In the code below, I'm adding a parameterValue for each row in the parameters datatable.

However, I'm getting the following error:

"The type arguments for method 'EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Select(EnumerableRowCollection, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Can someone help me understand what type argument I need to explicitly define in the code?

Here is the code with the error:

```
parameters.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
{
    ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
    parameterValue.Name = x["name"].ToString();
    parameterValue.Value = x["value"].ToString();
    parameterList.Add(parameterValue);
 });
```

This works fine in a foreach loop.  Here is the code for that:

```
foreach (DataRow row in parameters.Rows)
{
   ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
   parameterValue.Name = row["name"].ToString();
   parameterValue.Value = row["value"].ToString();

   parameterList.Add(parameterValue);
}
```

Comment: `Select` expects a function that returns the desired object. It's not a synonym for `ForEach` or `Apply`. In fact, it shouldn't have side-effects

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax of

```
parameters.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
{
    ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
    parameterValue.Name = x["name"].ToString();
    parameterValue.Value = x["value"].ToString();
    parameterList.Add(parameterValue);
 });
```

is

```
parameterList.AddRange(parameters.AsEnumerable().Select(x =>            
    new ParameterValue()
    {
        Name = x["name"].ToString(),
        Value = x["value"].ToString()
    }));
```

**Side note:**
instead of `x["name"].ToString()` you should access the field by its type `x.Field<string>("name")`

Comment: Depends on what `parameterList` is, maybe it doesn't have an `AddRange` method. I'd store the query in a variable and either use a `foreach` to add them one after  another or use `AddRange(allParameterValues)` if supported.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: my apologies. parameterList is: List<ParameterValue> parameterList = new List<ParameterValue>();

Comment: @fubo is using Field<string> a better practice because of type safety?

Comment: @rds80 you don't need any kind of convertion like `Convert.ToInt32(x["foo"])` and it's best practice https://stackoverflow.com/a/7104767/1315444

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.1) is a *projection* method. It projects each input item of type `TSource` into the new form of type `TResult`. Thus it accepts a *selector* delegate which does this TSource > TResult projection. Your selector delegate looks like this:

```
x => 
{
    ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
    parameterValue.Name = x["name"].ToString();
    parameterValue.Value = x["value"].ToString();
    parameterList.Add(parameterValue);
}
```

I.e. it takes `DataRow` as TSource and projects it to.. nothing. You do not return any value from this delegate. Thus compiler cannot understand which `TResult` it should use.

Now solution. Actually, you want to do two actions here:

- project each row to `ParameterValue`
- add each projected value to the list (new or existing)

First part is projection. Just use delegate which takes a `DataRow` as TSource and returns `ParameterValue` as TResult:

```
x => new ParameterValue{ Name = x.Field<string>("name"), Value = x.Field<string>("value") }
```

The second part can be done in two ways. You can create a new list from all parameter values. This is a declarative style of programming - instead of specifying how to add values to list you just say 'I want list':

```
var parameterList = parameters.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(r => new ParameterValue { 
          Name = r.Field<string>("name"), // note this LINQ to DataSet syntax
          Value = r.Field<string>("value")
      }).ToList();
```

Or you can use a simple foreach loop to add each projected value one by one to existing list. But here I would use query syntax for projection:

```
var parameterValues = from r in parameters.AsEnumerable()
                      select new ParameterValue { 
                          Name = r.Field<string>("name"),
                          Value = r.Field<string>("value")
                      };

foreach(var parameterValue in parameterValues)
    parameterList.Add(parameterValue);
```